# Cakephp 3.0 read local file contents using fget

Tags: php, csv, upload, cakephp-3.0

I have worked out the PHP code required to upload data from a .csv file to a database, not using CakePHP3.x, but I am struggling integrating this into my framework.  I don't want to upload the file to the database, only read the data from the CSV file.

This is my code that works on the localhost to upload the data to my database.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$fp = fopen("CSV_Upload_Test.csv", "r");

while( !feof($fp)) {
    if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '"')) {
        continue;
    }

    $mysqlimport = "INSERT INTO divisiontwosix.csvtestsystems VALUES('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."')";
    mysql_query($mysqlimport) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($fp);
```

This is my code for the CakePHP installation on my server, but I can't seem to find (or more likely ask the correct question to find) an answer on how to implement it.

This is my Controller:

```
   public function upload()
    {
        $system = $this->Systems->newEntity();
        //Check if file has been uploaded.
        if(!empty($this->request->data['Systems']['upload']['name']))
            {
                $file = $this->request->data['Systems']['upload'];
            }
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $system = $this->Systems->patchEntity($system, $this->request->data);
//          add upload data to controller function upload
            $file = $_REQUEST['text'];
            $fp = fopen("$file","r");
            while( !feof($fp)) {
    if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '"')) {
        continue;
    }

    $mysqlimport = "INSERT INTO divtwosix.systems VALUES('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."')";
    mysql_query($mysqlimport) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($fp);
            if ($this->Systems->save($system)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The system has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The system could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $estimates = $this->Systems->Estimates->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('system', 'estimates'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['system']);
    }
```

And this is my form (upload.ctp) as you can see I have tried a couple of things:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($system) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Upload System') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'create'), 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
//          echo $this->Form->create($system, ['type'=>'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('estimates_id', ['label'=>'Select Estimate Name','options' => $estimates]);
//          echo $this->Form->input('file', ['label'=>'Upload works with CSV files only','type' => 'file']);
            echo $this->Form->input('text', ['label'=>'Input File location']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Upload')) ?>
```

And the error I get is

```
fopen(C:\Users\jrogers\Desktop\Book1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Controller/SystemsController.php, line 86]
```

or

```
fopen(Book1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Controller/SystemsController.php, line 86]
```

It is not my intent to add the file to the database, but only to add the data from the .csv file to the database.  I realize I am probably missing something simple, but would greatly appreciate the assistance.  The examples I am finding only show how to upload the file to the database and not how to read the data from the local file.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using a text input for the file name instead of the file input that you have commented out? A text input will let you tell the server the name of the file, but that file is on your computer, not the server, so it's no wonder that it can't open it. You need to use a file input so that the file is sent to the server, where it will be accessible for reading in a tmp folder for the duration of that request.

Answer (score 0):

In legacy php scripts uploaded files should be accessed through $_FILES array so you should modify your code like this example

```
    $file = $_FILES['text']['tmp_name'];
    $fp = fopen($file,"r");
```

Good luck

source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

note: I'm not a cake user but IMO it should have a proper way for accessing uploaded files

Comment: Thanks, but still having same or similar issue.  I think I will have to upload the file to the database and use that as the source file.  I don't think it is pulling the information in from the csv.